# Trying to make Conway's Game of Life with Python

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to make Conway's Game of Life in Python (and am just putting it in my Discord bot, because why not). My problem is that when I run it, nothing happens, the message isn't edited. There are no error messages. I suppose the code thinks that nothing's changed from the last generation, so it stops, although something has.

Here's my code, I believe the problem is in either the surroundings function or the `for y, row in enumerate(grid):` loop.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def gameoflife(self, ctx):

        grid = [[0 for i in range(15)] for i in range(13)]
        grid[5][5], grid[5][6], grid[5][7] = (1, 1, 1) #just a simple blinker for now

        def emojify(i):
            convert = {0 : '⬛', 1 : '⬜'}
            return convert[i]

        gridmap = '\n'.join([''.join(list(map(emojify, i))) for i in grid])

        embed = discord.Embed(colour = 0xf1c40f)
        embed.set_author(name = 'CONWAY\'S GAME OF LIFE')
        embed.add_field(name = '_ _', value = gridmap, inline = False)
        embed.set_footer(text = 'Generation 1')
        m = await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        def surroundings(y, x):
            count = 0
            surrtiles = ((-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), 
                        (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, -1))
            for i in surrtiles:
                row = y
                column = x
                if row > 11 and i[0] == 1:
                    row = 0
                if column > 13 and i[1] == 1:
                    column = 0
                if grid[row + i[0]][column + i[1]] == 1:
                    count += 1
            return count

        gen = 1
        while True:
            gen += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(2.0)

            nextgrid = grid[:]
            for y, row in enumerate(grid):
                for x, column in enumerate(row):
                    if surroundings(y, x) == 3:
                        nextgrid[y][x] = 1
                    if surroundings(y, x) > 3:
                        nextgrid[y][x] = 0
                    if surroundings(y, x) < 2:
                        nextgrid[y][x] = 0

            if nextgrid == grid:
                break
            else:
                grid = nextgrid[:]

            gridmap = '\n'.join([''.join(list(map(emojify, i))) for i in grid])
            embed = discord.Embed(colour = 0xf1c40f)
            embed.set_author(name = 'CONWAY\'S GAME OF LIFE')
            embed.add_field(name = '_ _', value = gridmap, inline = False)
            embed.set_footer(text = f'Generation {gen}')
            await m.edit(embed = embed)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to look through. Could you maybe test a few components and narrow down the source of the problem?

Comment: @themadpsychologist I believe the problem is either in the surroundings function or the `for y, row in enumerate(grid):` loop.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: I've looked further into `nextgrid` and `grid`, and it seems that although `nextgrid` is a seperate copy of `grid`, the lists that it stores are not. I've fixed that, and everything works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Although `nextgrid` is a seperate copy of `grid`, the lists it stores are not. I just replaced `nextgrid = grid[:]` with `nextgrid = [i[:] for i in grid]`, and it works fine!